# Jquery text rotator issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show first container with text and then show and hide previous / next with some delay but the problem is that if i give a class .active to first .container with text js code remove and addClass again to first element but i need skip to second .container.. simply it makes delay 6s on first iteration instead 3s

```js
//Create a var to store the index of red element
var count = -1;
function AddRedClass() {
  var boxes = $('.topinfo-bar .container');
  var boxLength = boxes.length - 1;
  //Check if the actual item isn't more than the length then add 1 otherway restart to 0
  count < boxLength ? count++ : count=0;
  //Remove the class and add it to the new target
  boxes.removeClass('active').eq(count).addClass('active');
}

setInterval(AddRedClass, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container {if $item@first}active{/if}">
                <div class="topinfo-bar__wrapper">
                    <div class="topinfo-bar__icon">
                        <img src="./img/info.png" alt="info">
                    </div>
                    <div class="topinfo-bar__content">
                        <p class="default-paragraph">
                            {$item->info}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I can't understand your question well. Can you add one screenshot to explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your current markup, the JS shouldn't do much, as `$('.topinfo-bar .container')` doesn't match anything. But other than that, you're close.

Using a selector that actually matches elements in markup let's have a variable holding the `activeIndex` (makes it easy to control/check and set from outside scripts, should you ever need to...) and advance this index while we're always placing `active` class on the activeIndex class of the collection and remove it from the rest:

```js
let duration = 420, // these are miliseconds
  activeIndex = 0;  // first item to activate

function activateNext() {
  let boxes = $('.boxes > div');

  // activate current item
  boxes.removeClass('active').eq(activeIndex).addClass('active');
  
  // increase activeIndex and make reset at end of collection 
  if (++activeIndex >= boxes.length) activeIndex = 0;
  
  // run the function again after duration
  setTimeout(function() {
    activateNext(activeIndex);
  }, duration)
}

// start the loop
$(window).on('load', activateNext);
```

```css
.active {color: red;}
.boxes div {
  transition: color .1s linear;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>
```